# Проход по двумерному массиву в функции

Tags: c, массивы, segmentation-fault

У меня возникла ошибка, у меня есть поле (двумерный массив), и в нем есть цифры, у которых нужно поменять знак на противоположный, например есть `1, -2, 2` на выходе должно получиться `-1, 2, -2`.

В принципе ничего сложного тут нету, но у меня возникла ошибка segmentation fault. Я не знаю точное количество столбцов (вместо семи может быть другое значение), и соответственно, не знаю как закончить цикл.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
 
void swp(const int size, int array[][size]);

int main() {
    int array[7][3] = { {1,-2,2}, {-3,-13,-10},{1,3,-1},{-45,32,0},{13,0,0},    {-3,13,-11},{1,0,-1} };
    swp(3,array);
    for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            printf("%d ", array[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void swp(const int size, int array[][size]) {
    int pt = size;
    int pc = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < pt; x++) {
            if (array[y][x] == '\0') {
                pc = pc + 1;
            }
            array[y][x] = array[y][x] * -1;
        }
       if (pc == size) {
           break;
       } else {
        pc = 0;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот этот кусок`int array[7][3] `   в сочетании с вот этим куском `for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++){`  входит в конфликт тут `array[y][x] `  -  100 и 7  есть разница? Это приводит к фейлу.

Comment: При работе с массивами обязательно проверяйте выход за границы массива перед использованием массива. Если не можете проверить мысленно - проверяйте програмно, возможно на первое время делайте хотя бы так `if ((y < 0) || (y >=7)) {  printf("fail1"); return ; }`  позже освоите другие методы проверок или привыкните к этой особенности си.

Comment: Естественно, я понимаю , 100 я поставил как рандомное число, я просто незнаю какое будет значение int array, может быть array[10][3], array [5][2] и так далее, я просто написал функцию if (array[y][x] == '\0') которая выполняет break, но это не работает к сожалению

Comment: Не может быть 10. 10 даст сбой тоже. Если вы задали 7, 3 для array то ОДЗ для y [0,7) для x [0,3). Или задавайте другой масиив побольше и копируйте в него исходные значения, или как-то вкладывайтесь в рамки которые задали.

Comment: Вы чуть чуть не поняли, мне нужно лишь написать функцию, а значения для этой функции могут быть разные например в main будет задано не array[7][3] а array[11][3] и совсем другие числа. И я не могу поставить конкретное число вместо 100 в for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) потому что я банально незнаю сколько будет столбцов

Comment: Если вы задаёте статическое значение размерности - вы не должны выходить за пределы размеров которые изначально заданы. Именно нарушение этого правила приводит к фейлу. Выхода тут два. 1) задать массив сразу достаточно большого размера, такого что бы хватило. 2) использовать динамическое массивы или stl.

Comment: Вы наверно думаете что создали второй массив - но это не так. При передаче массива передаётся ссылка, и вы получаете выход за пределы массива. Так не получится. Нужно создать новый массив, и влить предзаданный в новый.

Comment: Ну давайте я еще раз попробую обьяснить, моя задача в этой программе написать лишь функцию void swp(const int size, int array[][size]), всё остальное задается автоматически,  тобишь мне нужно что бы эта функция работала как и для значения array[7][3] так и для значения array[10][3], потому что я незнаю какое значение будет в array.

Comment: Будет работать в будущем гипотетически, но проблема в другом. Сейчас проблема в вот этом куске `for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++){` там число больше чем 7 быть не может.

Comment: Проверяйте ОДЗ x y массива. Не выходите за ОДЗ и сбоя не будет.  Ещё, не запрещено обьявить больше, а "заполнить" меньше. Т.е. Можно `int array[7][3] = { {1` сделать вот так `int array[20][20] = { {1`  может вам так будет проще. Только размер 20 не меняйте на 3 тогда в аргументе size (т.е. все тройки на 20 заменить)

Comment: Я же говорю я значение array не задаю, все что находиться в main это лишь пример, один из множества, моя ГЛАВНАЯ задача это написать функцию void swp(const int size, int array[][size]), просто представьте что в main уже есть какое нибудь значение array и в эту программу всего лишь нужно добавить мою функцию, и всё

Comment: @oppo, вам же сказали, что сегфолт возникает из-за выхода за пределы массива. При передаче массива в функцию информация о его размере теряется. Вам нужно передавать **обе** размерности (и ширину, и высоту).

Answer (score 1):

Надо просто указать размеры массива в самой функции:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
 
void swp(const int size1, const int size2, int array[size1][size2]);

int main() {
    int array[7][3] = { {1,-2,2}, {-3,-13,-10},{1,3,-1},{-45,32,0},{13,0,0},    {-3,13,-11},{1,0,-1} };
    swp(7, 3,array);
    for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            printf("%d ", array[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void swp(const int size1, const int size2, int array[size1][size2]) {
    for (int y = 0; y < size1; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < size2; x++) {
            array[y][x] = array[y][x] * -1;
        }
    }
}
```